# Running command in cmd

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this code and I'm trying to run a `cmd` command 
on button click event:

```
private void _ddlbtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string ftype = _ftBox.Text; /// define the file type desired from _ftBox textbox
    string url = _urlBox.Text; /// define the url to download. from _urlBox textbox
    string upat = _pathlbl.Content.ToString(); /// define the path to save to from the the pre set path string
    string ucmd = "wget -r -P "+upat+" -A."+ftype+" --no-parent "+url;
    Process.Start("cmd.exe",ucmd); /// open cmd and run the command from the ucmd string

}
```

The `cmd` window opens but the string won't pass.

I am using Visual Studio 2013 if it matters.

Any ideas?

Comment: What does "the string won't pass" mean? Perhaps you have some spaces that should be considered?

Comment: That's not a proper command line for `cmd.exe`. At a minimum it should begin with `/C` or `/K`. https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html

Comment: Why are you using CMD.exe to run wget? Why aren't you just calling wget directly? Why complicate it with another layer? Then again, why are you using wget when C# has its own first class equivalents?

Comment: im trying to pass this to the cmd window: string ucmd = "wget -r -P "+upat+" -A."+ftype+" --no-parent "+url

Comment: well mason to be honest i thought i can't run the wget alone. but im sure going to try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    private void _ddlbtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string ftype = _ftBox.Text;  /// define file extension from filetype textbox
    string url = _urlBox.Text;  /// declare the url from text box
    string upat = _pathlbl.Content.ToString(); /// define the download to location
    string ucmd = "-r -P "+upat+" -A."+ftype+" --no-parent "+url; /// define full string to cmd arguments
    Process.Start("wget.exe",ucmd);
}
```

that worked for me

Answer (score 0):

When the cmd window opens it opens in the default directory or working directory.

DOS doesn't know about wget. You need to give it an absolute path, or put the information in the PATH environment variable.

Comment: that has nothing to do with my issue. cmd window opens but nothing gets to it. it just waits for input i can type commands and work with it but the command i was hoping would run there does not pass